# AGP 7.2.x jacoco coverage data is unexpectedly low

Tags: android, gradle, testing, code-coverage, jacoco

Starting with AGP 7.2.0-alpha01 and onwards (including 7.2.0, 7.3.x, and 7.4.x preview builds), jacoco coverage is not working correctly despite all config/information seemingly being setup/working as expected.

On AGP 7.1.3, coverage shows up to the expected %s (very high for my app I am using - above 90% lets say) - things are healthy.  When I switch to any newer AGP version, coverage drops to nearly something like 10% or less.  Some coverage data *does* show up, but most of the classes in the app show as uncovered.  I don't see a pattern for why some data shows up but some does not.  Classes tested only via instrumentation tests and other classes tested only via regular unit tests both have data missing - and the opposite exists too (meaning the data shows up for a small number of classes in these cases), so it's very confusing...

I setup my jacoco task like so:

```
task developDebugCodeCoverageReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDevelopDebugUnitTest', 'createDevelopDebugCoverageReport']) {
    group = 'Code Coverage'

    description = 'Generate Jacoco coverage reports for the developDebug build'

    reports {
        html.required.set(true)
        xml.required.set(true)
    }

    def excludes = [
        // list of files I want to exclude
    ]

    def javaClasses = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/developDebug/classes", excludes: excludes)
    def kotlinClasses = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/developDebug", excludes: excludes)
    classDirectories.setFrom(files([
            javaClasses,
            kotlinClasses
    ]))

    sourceDirectories.setFrom("${project.projectDir}/src/main/java")

    def junitTestsData = "${buildDir}/outputs/unit_test_code_coverage/developDebugUnitTest/testDevelopDebugUnitTest.exec"
    def androidTestsData = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/outputs/code_coverage/developDebugAndroidTest/connected/", includes: ["**/*.ec"])
    executionData.setFrom(files([
            junitTestsData,
            androidTestsData
    ]))
}
```

I assume AGP 7.2.x made some sort of change that broke how jacoco is able to read the coverage data.  The exec and ec files that are generated *are* different sizes after updating the AGP version... but I don't know enough about jacoco/AGP configs to continue on my own.

I'm trying to setup a small sample app that demonstrates the issue, I fear it's a related complexity with one of the dependencies I am using, but we'll see... in the meantime - anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I face the same issue, but only a ~10% drop

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue -- a huge coverage drop. I still haven't upgraded AGP because of this.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. So I'm still using AGP 7.1.3

Comment: In my case, it's because the `executionData` path should change after the AGP upgraded. But your case seems not because of this, so still have no idea.